# What is the purpose of these capacitors in series with LEDs?

Tags: led, capacitor, circuit-design

[image: schematic of emitter]

I am planning on building a device that sends IR light into a head at a specific intensity and detects the intensity that is measured by a photo diode.

I know that `VIN_LED` is from a linear regulator to keep the intensity constant for the LED, but what is the use of the capacitor after the LED (C4 and C5)?

Comment: C4 and C5 would give a nice 250 ns fade in and out for the LEDs?

Comment: @Transistor I saw an answer for that online but I don't see a reason they would need it or want it since the intensity needs to be tightly regulated and it would decrease the speed of sampling.

Comment: Alotta "circuit design by copying" method people will sprinkle capacitors where they're not really needed "just to be sure".  A 10nF cap is only going to significantly affect very high speed (high frequency) signals i.e. it could be filtering out radio frequency noise, etc...

Comment: The only reason for those LEDs would be to prevent voltage spikes due to inductivity in the traces of the layout. Those mosfet tend to switch pretty fast (especially because they are driven without gate resistors) and might be suspecible to ringing.. I'd guess they are there to cover other bad desicions in the design process.

Comment: Can be thought of as in parallel with low side control MOSFET rather than just series with LED.

Comment: The LED intensity is **not** tightly regulated by this circuit, not even close.